# Why ESP32 can't routing IP's

Tags: arduino, esp8266, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm working on a project where I need to set an esp32 as an access point, and some esp8266-01 as a client.

Then i running a web server on each of the esp822 chips to get the sensor data in json format. Now I have done this, when I connect to this network with my mobile and enter the IP of one of the esp8266s, i get response but with two special esp8266.

And other esp8266's there's get ip from access point but the web server doesn't send any response and timed out. I even tried 7 type esp8266 models but it didn't work, but when I replace the access point with the home modem instead of esp32. All of esp8266 works perfectly!!

I think the esp32 can't handle and route the IP's. But here is a contradiction, why those two models of esp8266 working perfectly amd other no??

**This is access point Code for ESP32**

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "esprouter";
const char* password = "9167997734";

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);

Serial.print("Setting AP (Access Point)…");
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
}

void loop(){

}
```

**And this is Client code for ESP8266's**

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#define DHTPin 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPin, DHTTYPE);

const char* ssid = "esprouter";
const char* password = "9167997734";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handle_OnConnect();
void handle_OnConnect2();
void handle_NotFound();

float Temperature;
float Humidity;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
dht.begin();

Serial.println("Connecting to ");
Serial.println(ssid);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(1000);
Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
Serial.print("IP: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

server.on("/info", handle_OnConnect);
server.on("/get", handle_OnConnect2);

server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
server.begin();
dht.begin();
}
void loop() {

server.handleClient();

}

void handle_OnConnect() {
DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
doc["type"] = "dht-sensor" ;
doc["id"] = 128;
doc["ip"] = WiFi.localIP().toString();
String response;
serializeJson(doc, response);
server.send(200, "content/json", response);
}

void handle_OnConnect2() {

Temperature = dht.readTemperature();
Humidity = dht.readHumidity();
DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
doc["temp"] = Temperature;
doc["hum"] = Humidity;
String response;
serializeJson(doc, response);
server.send(200, "content/json", response);

}

void handle_NotFound(){
server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Thanks if anyone can guide me...

Comment: I haven't created an ESP32 network this complex before, but I have used them as both clients and APs. If you post your code and possibly wiring diagrams, or even better, a minimal reproducible example, you are more likely to get help.

Comment: It seems that you jump into the conclusion without some diagnosis. And you didn't provide any meaningful information for people to help you. My question to you is assuming the two esp8266 works as you expected, what the other esp8266 connected to? if it failed to establish a connection with AP, any error messages? Also do some logging on the ESP32 on network activities. Do some diagnosis...

Comment: @deaton.dg 
OK, i added code of devices

Comment: @hcheung OK, i added code of devices, please check it

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any problems here, but I don't have much experience with the arduino IDE or the ESP32 arduino API. This probably isn't much help, but I have never had any issues using an ESP32 as an AP when coding with the esp32-idf. You could try this example: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/softAP. Otherwise, we will need detailed logs of how exactly these devices are failing.